# Homebrew not listing Git but it's installed

Tags: git, homebrew

Ok, so, I've just noticed that when I do a `brew list`, Homebrew does not list me Git anymore... But, when I try `brew install git`it says that Git is already install and my prompt is using the right Git (the one install by Homebrew so).

Even if it's a big deal now, I'ld still like to know if there is a way to solve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew requires Git, so you would have installed Git some other way before you could even have installed Homebrew. That's why it's not appearing in the list of brews being managed.